# Fit to box with two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m working on a resize effect with jquery (no css)

The problem I have is that the resize it´s working OK on the images, but I just can´t make it put two images on the same row, like the design. If the image is horizontal it would be one per line but if it´s vertical it should arrange two per line with the resizing working on both, any idea how to achieve this?

this is my script:

```
    $('.gallery_item').each(function(){
        $('.gallery_img').each(function(){
            var ww = $(window).width() - 60 - 230;
            var wh = $(window).height() - 60;
            var iar = $(this).attr('height') / $(this).attr('width');
            var war = wh / ww;
            if(iar <= war){
                $(this).attr("width" , ww);
                $(this).attr("height" , ww * iar);
            }else{
                $(this).attr("height" , wh);
                $(this).attr("width" , wh / iar);
            }
            $('.gallery_item').css({
                'width' : $(this).attr('width'),
                'height' : $(this).attr('height'),
                'padding-bottom' : 0
            });
        });
    })

    $(window).bind('resize' , function(){

    $('.gallery_item').each(function(){
        $('.gallery_img').each(function(){
            var ww = $(window).width() - 60 - 230;
            var wh = $(window).height() - 60;
            var iar = $(this).attr('height') / $(this).attr('width');
            var war = wh / ww;
            if(iar <= war){
                $(this).attr("width" , ww);
                $(this).attr("height" , ww * iar);
            }else{
                $(this).attr("height" , wh);
                $(this).attr("width" , wh / iar);
            }
            $('.gallery_item').css({
                'width' : $(this).attr('width'),
                'height' : $(this).attr('height'),
                'padding-bottom' : 0
            });
        });
    })

    });
```

and my markup:

```
                    <div class="gallery_item">
                        <img class="gallery_img" src="img/gallery0.jpg" alt="gallery0" width="850" height="567">
                        <img class="gallery_img vertical_img" src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="gallery1" width="380" height="570">
                        <img class="gallery_img vertical_img" src="img/gallery2.jpg" alt="gallery2" width="382" height="570">
                    </div>
```

I have tried using float:left on .vertical_img with no luck.

Comment: Why don't you put the images in divs and then float the block elements. IMG tags are inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display:inline;` on `.vertical_img` should put both of those images on the same line. If their combined width is greater than the width of their container then they will appear on different lines, however.

Your container (`div.gallery_item`) is only 250px wide, which preventing this from working. Your large image actually exceeds the boundaries of this container. This container will need to be the width of the [outerWidth](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerWidth) of the two images combined (or greater).

Comment: yeah i´m trying to get the wide of the image, is the script wrong?

Comment: Your script is setting the width of the container to the width of the last smaller image, by the look of it. `$('.gallery_item').css({'width' : $(this).attr('width') ...` is setting the width of the `.gallery_item` (container) to the width of the `.gallery_img` (image) - and as it loops through it will set it as the width of the first image, the second, then finish up by setting it as the width of the final image in the loop, meaning the container will always equal the size (width AND height) of the final image.

Comment: One way would be to compare the heights. Outside of the loop, put `var imgWidth = 0;`, and within the loop add a check: `if($(this).outerWidth() > imgWidth) { imgWidth = $(this).outerWidth(); }`. That way the final `imgWidth` variable would contain the widest image's width at the end of the loop. Then you can set the container width OUTSIDE the loop - so as to only set it once and not setting it per image.

Comment: Did you get it working? If so, could you please mark this as the accepted answer? If not, I should be able to help out if you're still stuck. Ta!